# Day, Line and Picture types cannot be resolved

Tags: java

Good day all. Recently downloaded Oracle and JDK. Started with a basic Java course at Udacity. Got some basics down, but having problems.

Day , Line and Picture types cannot be resolved. Entered the code as explained and did some research on how to use them, but it with no success.

Might it be something I haven't installed?

Ps. These are just the types I've tried so far, so I'm unsure if there are others that might do the same.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here, and edit your question accordingly.  See also: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Well which package do you *expect* those types to be in, and why do you expect them to be there? I suspect they're part of code that the course expects you to have downloaded... I suggest you revisit the early parts of the course.

Comment: Share the code and what is problem you are facing?

Comment: I don't know how Udacity works, but can you post the full code you are using? It seems you are missing some imports.